# Two choices with the same name but different value both result in same value (discord.py)

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

```
choices = []
choices.append(app_commands.Choice(name="Foo", value=1))
choices.append(app_commands.Choice(name="Foo", value=2))

@bot.tree.command(name="abc", description="123")
@app_commands.choices(myarg=choices)
async def abc(ctx: discord.Interaction, myarg: int):
     assert(myarg==1) # will always be triggered
```

Two choices will appear with the same visual name, but both will yield one, or I assume whatever is added first. Changing the name of one or both choices will resolve this issue, but I need two choices with the same name.

I am expecting two options with the same name but different values.